# как правильно вызвать функцию делегат внутри другой функции?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, serial

Подскажите как вызвать функцию из другой функции?
Создал проект для чтения последовательного порта, пытаюсь записать в текстовое поле `textbox1` строку `dataIN`если последовательный порт отправляет данные. компилятор ругается в этом месте: `this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::ShowData));`

```
public: String^ dataIN;
MyForm(void)
{...
```

...

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, 
System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e)
{
dataIN = serialPort1->ReadExisting();
this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::ShowData));
}

private: System::Void ShowData(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox1->Text = dataIN;
}
```

Comment: Матом ругается? Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: `ShowData(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)`

Comment: А зачем люди пишут `this->`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Александр, СПАСИБО! полночи с бубном танцевал, изучал `С++/CLI`, оказалось не там ставил символ указателя `^` %)

нашел пример на `C#` и хотел его переделать на `C++/CLI`, но у этого языка специфический синтаксис, вроде ставил `^`, но не там

Comment: Правильно использовать делегаты, в вашем случае https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-define-and-use-delegates-cpp-cli?view=vs-2017 , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/delegate-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

код на C++/CLI

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, 
System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e)
{
dataIN = serialPort1->ReadExisting();
this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::ShowData));
}
```

//вызываемая функция `ShowData`

```
private: System::Void ShowData(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
textBox1->Text = dataIN;
}
```

код на C#

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(Object  sender,  
SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
dataIN = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ShowData));
}
```

//вызываемая функция `ShowData`

```
private void ShowData(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox1.Text = dataIN;
}
```